# Name of the distribution with density $P(x) e^{-x/\theta}$, where $P$ is a polynomial with positive coefficients.

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology, gamma-distribution

The [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) of shape $k$ and scale $\theta$ has density $\frac1{\Gamma(k)\theta(k)} x^{k-1} e^{-x/\theta}$.
Consider the more general distribution with density (up to a normalizing constant)  $P(x) e^{-x/\theta}$, where $P$ is a polynomial with positive coefficients. Does this distribution have a name?

Comment: If $P$ had all nonnegative coefficients then this would just be a convex combination of the sorts of Gamma distributions that you described. (Incidentally, these are sometimes called Erlang distributions when $k$ is an integer; your suggestion generalizes Erlang distributions but does not generalize Gamma distributions, strictly speaking.) So in this case I doubt there is any name. When it has negative coefficients I'm not sure what to call it.

Comment: @Ian. You are right with your remark about Erlang distributions, thanks. I restricted the question to the case where the coefficients are positive. So, as you say, one can call it _convex combination, or [finite mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures), of Gamma distributions_. If you want, I let you write an answer in order you get the credits. Otherwise I'll post an answer next week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination#Other_objects), or equivalently a [finite mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures), of Gamma distributions with shape parameter $1,2,\dots,n$ and scale parameter $\theta$, where $n-1$ is the degree of $P$. The nonnegativity of the coefficients of $P$ is crucial to this statement, whereas it is not crucial to this density being well-defined. For example, there is such a distribution with $P(x)=x^2-x+1$, which is *not* a mixture of Gamma distributions.